# Number equality test fails in CLIPS pattern matching?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, expert-system, clips, jess

I have this following rule in my CLIPS file:

```
(defrule check-final (declare (salience 12))
    ?scnt <- (set-count (value ?v) (class ?c))
    (test (= ?v ?*total*))
    =>
    (printout T ?*total* " == " ?v crlf)
)
```

And I get the following strange output:

```
CLIPS>(run)
14 == 9
5 == 2
```

How is this possible ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching for this rule occurs whenever the fact `set-count` is asserted or modified. The rule is fired some time afterwards, during the call to `run`. These two processes can be widely separated in time. The value of `?*v*` can of course change during that long period of time.

The key is to realize that he printed results will reflect the value of `?v` from the the epoch during which pattern matching happened, while `?*total*` will be the value when the results are printed. Since `?*total*` may have seen arbitrary changes since the pattern matching, there's no guarantee that it will be equal to `?v` when the rule actually fires.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I fixed it eventually be losing the global and replacing it with a fact. Thank you again for the great answer.

Comment: I just noticed that you suggested an edit for my answer, but it got rejected before I had a chance to accept it. Your edit was completely right, for what it's worth, and I've applied it here.

Answer (score 0):

Found part of the problem: I'm using the global `?*total*` and according to the 
[CLIPS Manual](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v624/bpg.htm)

> Global variables can be accessed as part of the pattern‑matching
>   process, but changing them does not invoke the pattern‑matching
>   process.

But this does not explain the equality test failure

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that at some point the equality test is being satisfied and then the value of the global is changed before the rule executes.

```
CLIPS> (deftemplate set-count (slot value) (slot class))
CLIPS> 
(defglobal ?*total* = 0)
CLIPS> 
(defrule check-final (declare (salience 12))
    ?scnt <- (set-count (value ?v) (class ?c))
    (test (= ?v ?*total*))
    =>
    (printout T ?*total* " == " ?v crlf)
)
CLIPS> (bind ?*total* 9)
9
CLIPS> (assert (set-count (value 9) (class a)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (bind ?*total* 14)
14
CLIPS> (run)
14 == 9
CLIPS> (bind ?*total* 2)
2
CLIPS> (assert (set-count (value 2) (class b)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (bind ?*total* 5)
5
CLIPS> (run)
5 == 2
CLIPS>
```